# How was this map made by qgis2web

Tags: qgis-3, legend, filter, qgis2web

I have a layer with some points and I want to publish it using qgis2web. I have seen some exampes where the legend can be filtered such as in this webmap: https://ukerc.rl.ac.uk/TOOLS/EnergyDemonstrators/map.html#5/55.674/-2.490

[image: webmap using qgis2web]

What setting was used to make this filtered legend? The closest I can make is this where I can only filter the layers themselves.:

[image: my attempt]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the example you link to has separate layers, whereas yours is one layer, rendered with multiple styles (eg categorized, graduated, or rule-based). I'm afraid qgis2web only creates visibility checkboxes for whole layers, not for categories/ranges/rules within a layer's renderer.

The workaround is to create a separate layer for each of your categories/ranges/rules.